# Custom order for Apache Solr

Tags: apache, search, solr

I want to sort my Solr results using the score (returned by solr) and other two fields of the indexed info, in this way:

score*0.45 + field1*0.45 + field2*0.1 DESC

Is there some way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[FunctionQuery](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries) should do what you want and a lot more.

However, you may also want to look at [boosts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thebf(BoostFunctions)Parameter) using those two fields. That way you may be able to build those field impacts right into the query itself, rather than into the sort.